# Problem with bad topology

Tags: modeling, topology

*Sorry for miserable english.*

Here is my problem: I made model by stupidly circling circuit.
With smooth shading it makes me sad. I understand that bad topology is the crux of problem but don't know how to make it better.
Whether there is a way to make this shape with adequate topology?

My blender file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-tV3odolwlZDg1eDdWbU5mSnM/view?usp=sharing
[image]
[image]

Comment: Add an "Edge Split" Modifier or "Bevel" Modifier. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html

Comment: I know about  these modifiers, I tried both of them - bevel doesn't make it better, `Edge Split`  fixed the problem. But I want to hear some advices about avoiding n-gon in my case, if it possible.

Comment: I think the best is to do it again. That can be fast starting from a circle (with not too much vertices). From that, remove unnecessary vertex, extrude and make quads...

Comment: I'm mostly confused with the circular part of the mesh. Do u mean that I must use `Boolean` modifier  in this case?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need for Boolean. It's enough to add a circle from 16 verts, adjust it with the center part of image so vertices get in the corners of those details and extrude the circle inside, then close it with Grid Fill. That will be enough for the main part.